# How to dynamically set Current_ Frame in Driver Namespace Function Call?

Tags: python, drivers

The driver namespace function call(wiggle_z) gives a float error even when float values are provided for the framerange in the driver scripted expression field .

How to resolve this ?

***TEST  CALL***

```
wiggle_z(50.0,200.0)
```

***ERROR:***

```
Error in Driver: The following Python expression failed:
    'wiggle_z(50.0,200.0)'
TypeError: a float is required
```

***SCRIPT:***

```
import bpy
ob  = bpy.context.object 
scene = bpy.context.scene
frame_current = bpy.app.driver_namespace["frame"]

import math   

def wiggle_z(frame_start,frame_end):

    if frame_current > frame_start and frame_current < frame_end:
        ob.rotation_euler[2] = math.sin(frame_current)/ 10

    else:
        ob.rotation_euler[2] = 0 



bpy.app.driver_namespace["wiggle_z"] = wiggle_z #wiggles object around Z axis within frame_range


#def main():             
#    wiggle_z(50.0,200.0) #Test Call
#main()
```

Comment: Hello, what are you trying to do with this script ? After a quick look at the documentation https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/workflow_examples.html you are supposed to use square brackets, not parentheses after `driver_namespace`. You can look into the Templates > Python > Driver functions in the script editor

Comment: Since `bpy.app.driver_namespace` is a dictionary, using round brackets is "calling" it like a method would result in  `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`   However you are overriding this error with `foo() = 4`  ie trying to assign to a function call. @Gorgious  add as answerf... or do I kill it as more a python question?

Comment: btw the way you are using frame current will not work as expected either it will have only the value when the script to register the method is run.  It is known to the driver namespace as "frame" .. can pass it to driver method eg `foo(frame, start_frame, end_frame)` or get it from driver namespace `frame_current = driver_namespace["frame"]`  or make it a driver variable Scene object, data path "frame_current".

Comment: Plz don.t post the answer as the main question is about the use of frames in driver namespace .I will check and revise the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Return the value from a driver, don't set it.**

So many things wrong with such a little script.

In addition to comments below question:

Don't mix context and drivers, the driver returns a value to the property it is driving.  To drive the z rotation of an object with wiggle, simply type directly into field.  Using hash as first character when first entering informs blender to treat input as  a driver expression `#wiggle(1, 35)`

Here it is seen as purple (a driver) after being added as above

[image]

The frame is known to the driver namespace as "frame", have used that rather than passing frame via arguments or setting up a variable using scene.

```
import bpy
from bpy.app import driver_namespace as dns
from math import sin

def wiggle(frame_start, frame_end):
    frame = dns["frame"] # saves passing it
    if frame_start <= frame <= frame_end:
        return sin(frame) / 10
    return 0.0

dns["wiggle"] = wiggle
```